# Laravel wherePivot with sync method not working

Tags: laravel, many-to-many, laravel-5.5

I am trying to sync data but error occur.

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'model_type' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `model_has_roles` (`dealer`, `dealership_id`, `model_id`, `role_id`) values (1, 61, 85, 13))

// controller code

```
$user = User::findOrFail($id);
        $user->first_name = $request->get('first_name');
        $user->last_name = $request->get('last_name');
        $user->phone = $request->get('phone_no');
        $user->title = $request->get('title');
        $user->mobile = $request->get('mobile');
        $user->save();

        $user->dealerRoles()->wherePivot('dealership_id', session('dealership_id'))->sync([$request->get('role_id') => ['dealer' => true, 'dealership_id' => session('dealership_id')]]);
```

// User Model

```
public function dealerRoles()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Role::class, 'model_has_roles', 'model_id', 'role_id');
}
```

Comment: In your table `model_has_roles` column `model_type` is required. You have to set value also for this column.

Comment: @RafałMigda how to set that value?

Comment: You need to add to sync method

$user->dealerRoles()->wherePivot('dealership_id', session('dealership_id'))->sync([$request->get('role_id') => [
'model_type' => 1,
'dealer' => true, 'dealership_id' => session('dealership_id')]]);

Comment: Okay Thank You so much now working

Comment: @RafałMigda Please can you add this as an answer? I t might help someone else with this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add to sync method

```
$user->dealerRoles()
              ->wherePivot('dealership_id', session('dealership_id'))
                  ->sync([
                       $request->get('role_id') => [ 
                            'model_type' => 1, 
                            'dealer' => true, 
                            'dealership_id' => session('dealership_id')
                   ]
        ]);
```